# The name "Class1" does not exist in the namespace "using:Binding_2"

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

```xaml
<page>
x:Class="Binding_2.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Binding_2"
    xmlns:data="using:Binding_2"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Page.DataContext>
        <local:Class1/>
    </Page.DataContext>
</page>
```

And i have a `class1` in `namespace Binding_2`

```cs
namespace Binding_2
{
    class Class1
    {
        public Class1()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

But it's not working and showing the error:

> The name "Class1" does not exist in the namespace "using:Binding_2"

Comment: There is no issue in your code, you should be able to clean your project and  rebuild your project. If it does not work, please try to repair your VS.

Answer (score 1):

The default scope of a class in C# is `internal`, make it `public`:

```
namespace Binding_2
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public Class1()
        {

        }
    }
}
```